# SearchView is not refreshing when searching for specific description in the ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, searchview, android-search

I am implementing search function for my auction list. I could filter what I typed in the SearchView, but when I delete the fields, it does not refresh. Why is that so?I believe my codes already took that into consideration under the onQueryTextChange. Please advise.

AuctionList.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu,menu);

    final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)myActionMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                mListView.clearTextFilter();
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter("");
            } else {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

AuctionAdapter.java:

```
public class AuctionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    ValueFilter valueFilter;


    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<Model> auctionList;





    public AuctionListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Model> auctionList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.auctionList = auctionList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return auctionList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return auctionList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Model> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < auctionList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((auctionList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())||(auctionList.get(i).getDescription().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())||(auctionList.get(i).getPrice().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())||(auctionList.get(i).getDuration().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        Model model = new Model(auctionList.get(i).getId(),auctionList.get(i).getName(),
                                auctionList.get(i).getDescription(),auctionList.get(i).getPrice(),auctionList.get(i).getDuration()
                                ,auctionList.get(i).getImage());
                        filterList.add(model);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = auctionList.size();
                results.values = auctionList;
            }
            return results;


        }


        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            auctionList = (ArrayList<Model>) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    }



private class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName,txtDescription,txtPrice,txtDuration;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout,null);
        holder.txtName=row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtDescription=row.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        holder.txtPrice=row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        holder.txtDuration=row.findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);
        holder.imageView=row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Model model = auctionList.get(position);

    holder.txtName.setText(model.getName());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(model.getPrice());
    holder.txtDuration.setText(model.getDuration());


    byte[] auctionImage = model.getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(auctionImage,0,auctionImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return row;



}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code. please review the changes and let me know if you are still facing any issue.

**AuctionList.java:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);

    final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**AuctionAdapter.java:**

```
public class AuctionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {



private Context context;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<Model> auctionList,filterAuctionAl;


public AuctionListAdapter() {
}

public AuctionListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Model> auctionList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.auctionList = auctionList;
    filterAuctionAl = auctionList;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filterAuctionAl.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filterAuctionAl.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
   return new ValueFilter();
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            String content= constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            ArrayList<Model> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filterAuctionAl.size(); i++) {
                if ((filterAuctionAl.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(content))
                        ||(filterAuctionAl.get(i).getDescription().toUpperCase().contains(content))
                        ||(filterAuctionAl.get(i).getPrice().toUpperCase().contains(content))
                        ||(filterAuctionAl.get(i).getDuration().toUpperCase().contains(content))) {
                    Model model = new Model(filterAuctionAl.get(i).getId(),filterAuctionAl.get(i).getName(),
                            filterAuctionAl.get(i).getDescription(),filterAuctionAl.get(i).getPrice(),filterAuctionAl.get(i).getDuration()
                            ,filterAuctionAl.get(i).getImage());
                    filterList.add(model);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = auctionList.size();
            results.values = auctionList;
        }
        return results;


    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        filterAuctionAl = (ArrayList<Model>) results.values;

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}



private class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName,txtDescription,txtPrice,txtDuration;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout,null);
        holder.txtName=row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtDescription=row.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        holder.txtPrice=row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        holder.txtDuration=row.findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);
        holder.imageView=row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Model model = filterAuctionAl.get(position);

    holder.txtName.setText(model.getName());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(model.getPrice());
    holder.txtDuration.setText(model.getDuration());


    byte[] auctionImage = model.getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(auctionImage,0,auctionImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return row;

}
```

}

Let me know in case of any query!

Thank You.

Comment: I actually have another issue with my app and I am done with my whole app.Are you able to help me out,please?

Comment: sure, tell me about your query.

Comment: I just posted the issue.How do I tag you in that?

Comment: I got your new post.

Comment: Thanks,hope you understand what I'm trying to ask as I'm an amateur.I can send you the video of my issue if you don't mind. You could pass me you contact details?

Comment: first, let me understand your code.if I required anything then I'll let you know.

Comment: This is the link to my issue in video. I am not sure why the comment in the other post got deleted.